# Template::Error undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello I have a Rails application in production, and recently i started getting totally random errors on the loading of the show method of my "complaints" controller .

My "complaints" table has a one-to-one relationship with "interactions" table, you can create an interaction then create a complaint.

I display my data in a table on complaints#index, then I click on a row to get to complaints#show

I get this error :

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
     7:       <div class="uk-width-expand@m">
     8:         <h1 class="uk-heading-primary">
     9:           <%# <%= link_to 'Retour à l\'interaction', interaction_path(@variables[:complaint].interaction, search: @params[:search]), class: 'uk-button uk-button-default uk-margin-right' %>
    10:           <%= I18n.t("kind.#{@variables[:complaint].kind}") %>
    11:           <% if @variables[:complaint].interaction.date.present? %>
    12:             - <%= @variables[:complaint].interaction.date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') %>
    13:           <% end %>
  
app/views/complaints/show.html.erb:10:in `_app_views_complaints_show_html_erb__763547916_154685640'
```

**But this error appears totaly randomly**. That means if I refresh the page, it may launch this time. So because of this, i can't understand where this error comes from, most of the time there is no error, but I get complaints from the app users saying they are really bothered.

Here is my controller show method :

```
def show
complaint = Complaint.find_by(id: params[:id])
if complaint.blank?
  redirect_to complaints_path
  return
end
interaction = Interaction.find(complaint.interaction.id)
result = DetailCommande.execute_procedure "p_detail_commande", interaction.do_piece, interaction.do_type
contenu_commande = DetailCommande.execute_procedure "p_contenu_commande", interaction.do_piece, interaction.do_type
@variables = { complaint: complaint, detail_commande: result[0], contenu_commande: contenu_commande }
@params = { search: params[:search] }
end
```

Here is the part of my complaints#show view that causes trouble :

```
    <div class="uk-flex-middle uk-margin-small" uk-grid>
  <div class="uk-width-expand@m">
    <h1 class="uk-heading-primary">
        <%= link_to 'Retour à l\'interaction', interaction_path(id: params[:id], search: @params[:search]), class: 'uk-button uk-button-default uk-margin-right' %>
        <%= I18n.t("kind.#{@variables[:complaint].kind}") %>
      <% if @variables[:complaint].interaction.date.present? %>
        - <%= @variables[:complaint].interaction.date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') %>
      <% end %>
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="uk-width-auto@m">
    <% if @variables[:complaint].control.present? %>
      <button class="uk-button uk-button-default" disabled>Contrôle</button>
    <% else %>
      <a href="#modal-control-<%= params[:id] %>" class="uk-button uk-button-warning" uk-toggle>Contrôle</a>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to 'Modifier', edit_complaint_path(id: @variables[:complaint].id, search: @params[:search]), class: 'uk-button uk-button-primary' %>
    <%= link_to 'Supprimer', complaint_path(@variables[:complaint], search: @params[:search]), method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Êtes-vous sûr ?'}, class: 'uk-button uk-button-danger' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is a [screen of my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VA9Ix.png) when it actually loads. Just simple data display

I don't know if i provided enough informations, but thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Could you provide full stack trace error? I suspect it have an error on your view ``` 10: <%= I18n.t("kind.#{@variables[:complaint].kind}") %>
``` or maybe the `result` in your controller might spit out nil value?

Comment: the error means that @variables is nil and vecause of that you cannot call the method `[]` on it. when you do this `@variables[:complaint]` it is also just a method call - you could also write it like this: `@variables.[](:complaint). 
Any idea, why @variables could be empty? My only guess it, that it should be `redirect_to complaints_path && return` in your controller, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your application is running on 2 servers , sharing the load by load balancer.
I think so because of the following 2 cases:

1. See line no. 9 of your log i.e.

```
 9:  <%# <%= link_to 'Retour à l\'interaction', interaction_path(@variables[:complaint].interaction, search: @params[:search]), class: 'uk-button uk-button-default uk-margin-right' %>
```

and your html file does not contains this code, this are some changes in show.html i.e.

```
<%= link_to 'Retour à l\'interaction', interaction_path(id: params[:id], search: @params[:search]), class: 'uk-button uk-button-default uk-margin-right' %>
```

2. This error gone on page refresh, it means that 1 server contains correct code and 1 contains wrong code, so when the request goes on server 1, it displays the page and when it goes on server2, it gives error.

As per the logs, I think that `complaint.kind` is empty.